# EAV Query dynamic fields to column

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have the following tables:

```
Dataentry
---------
name
id

DataentryRows
----------
id
dataentry_id


Fields
----------
dataentry_id
name
id

DataentryValue
----------
id
value
field_id
dataentry_row_id
```

I want to create a query to retrieve all the DataentryRows of a dataentry, where a DataEntryRow should includes all the fields name and the specific value.

The issue I am facing is that the number of fields is dynamic and I want to produce a column for each field of a dataentry.

Example data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1f66

Comment: SQL is not designed to return a variable number of columns. So simply select rows and turn them into columns in a loop in your app.

Comment: you can do it with prepared sql. post the data on http://sqlfiddle.com/  and the result that you want then i writes a query for you

Comment: Well I definitely not need this for my app, I need to provide access to the db with a query.

Comment: @BerndBuffen done, schema and sample data are on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1f66/

Comment: cant open i. its empty

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c1f66 @BerndBuffen is working for me

Comment: @Kerby82 - now its also working for me. Can you please give me two more things. 1. what your desired result looks like with at least 2 rows to see if and which values ​​are below each other and 2. a simple query to get the result row by row to see how you join. You can attach this to your question or send it to me by e-mail (profile)